C# Как сериализовать\десериализовать список контролов в JSON
Создается неопределенное количество Лейблов, добавляется в лист Labels, его необходимо сериализовать и десериализовать. Буду благодарен за помощь!
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();
        public static List<Label> DeLabels = new List<Label>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label newLabel = new Label();
            Label lastLabel = Labels.LastOrDefault();
            if (lastLabel == null)
            {
                newLabel.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                newLabel.Text = $"label_{Labels.Count}";
            }
            else
            {
                newLabel.Location = new Point(lastLabel.Location.X, lastLabel.Location.Y + 50);
                newLabel.Text = $"label_{Labels.Count}";
            }
            Labels.Add(newLabel);            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Сериализация Labels JSON
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Десериализация JSON DeLabels
        }
    }
}```


Никак, вы не должны вообще данные в UI хранить, и уж тем более их де/сериализовать. Вы должны работать с данными, у вас не должно быть всяких lastLabel == null, у вас должны быть отдельные классы, которые в себе содержать что-то, что требуется вашему приложению, а уже на основе этих данных вы делаете UI, с нужными леймблами, кнопками, и прочим. И вот тогда уже вы де/сериализуете данные.

Выше упомянутый код написан для понимая сути вопроса(де\сериализацияй  списка контролов). В приложении динамически создается пара техтбокс + (1-5) лейблов, из текстбокса , в зависимости от выбранной логики, вносятся изминения в лейбл\ы, таких пар от 4 до 200, необходимо сериализовать и передать данные настройки другому пользователю. Т.е. вместо двух списков лейбл и текстбок, мне нужно создать 4-200 экземпляра класса, которые будут хранить все теже лейблы и текстбоксы, и уже их де\сериализовать? или я чтото не так понял?

Ничего не понял из описания задачи, сумбурно все. Еще раз повторю - вы обязаны отделить данные от UI. Вот хотите к примеру генерацию лейблов вынести в JSON: Делаете класс, который будет описывать данные конкретного леймба, ну условно class Some { public string Text {get; set;} }, далее делаете коллекцию этих классов, что-то вроде такого var data = new List<Some>{ new() { Text = "123" } }, затем имея данные, уже делаете UI (лучше привязками), но допустим пойдем как вы: foreach (var someData in data) { var label = new Label(); label.Text = someData.Text; }, готово.

Пример очень упрощенный, но суть думаю поняли. Повторю - данные отделяете от UI, это самое важное. Ну а де/сериализация делается очень просто - var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data); и обратно var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Some>>(data);, будет у вас простой JSON примерно такого вида: [ { "Text": "123" } ]. Спросите "зачем отделять, когда у меня есть все в UI классе? А все просто, 1. UI не должен ничего знать про данные. 2. Не каждый UI пригоден для серилазации. 3. Вы получаете кучу лишних, бесполезных для вас данных. Так что, отделняйте и забудьте про хранение в UI.

очень примерно понял, что то похожее я нашел на бинарной сериализации, почемуто показалось что json можно не заморачиваясь слать весь обьект целиком(видимо ошибся). тогда есть пару уточняющих вопросов 1. как быть с полями типа  textBox1.Font = new Font("SolidWorks GDT", 12F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point, 204);  FontStyle.Italic GraphicsUnit.Point и textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown; textBox1_KeyDown. 2. если не затруднить немножко подробней про сериализацию. зарание спасибо!!!

для отмеченных мною полей создавать в классе свойства string?

Шрифт тоже опишите классом, вам явно не все свойства там нужны. Обычно данные для хранения где либо - это сам шрифт, размер, да и всякие "модификаторы" по типу жирный, курсив, и т.д., все, этого в 90% достаточно. Ну и вот получаете 3 свойства в отдельном классе, который описывает шрифт, дальше все по аналогии. textBox1_KeyDown - А вот тут вы делаете вообще что-то странное, ибо вы хотите сохранять еще то, что вообще не сохраняют, а именно, поведение. Если у вас объект выполняет все сразу, и это еще и меняется, то у вас вообще нарушены принципы проектирования по типу SRP и др.

Не, конечно есть системы, где пользователь выбирает "действие", которое должно выполняться по условному событию, но там не сохраняется ведь само "действие", там сохраняется либо тип выполняемого действия, либо некий его идентификатор. Вот это и делайте. То есть, у вас у всех компонентов идет привязка на один обработчик события, в котором вы делаете что-то такое, где сверяете некий текстовый "триггер" с набором действий, ну и если это триггер соответсвует чему либо, то выполняете это дейтсвие. Соответственно и сохранять придется текст.

как писал выше, в приложении создаются пары техбокса с лейблами. и в зависимости от поставленой задачи выбирается нужный алгоритм, (подписывается на нужное событие, в котором реализован тот самый алгоритм) как пример ето могут быть textBox1_KeyDown, textBox2_KeyDown, textBox3_KeyDown и тд.  сами события будут реализованы изначально и сериализации не требуют. не совсем пойму как в данном примере textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown он "скушает" string вместо имени события

Я вам дал ссылку на подробный ответ с реализацией. Изучайте, пробуйте. P.S. Объяснение по типу "есть ряд текстбоксов и надо сделать то-то" довольно сложно представить в голове человеку, который не знаком с реальной задачей. На будущее, если хотите объяснить людям, то лучше писать то, какую задачу вы конкретно решаете, а не абстракция в виде "кнопочек, лейблов, тексбоксов.

Я смотрел по вашей ссылке, ето не совсем то что нужно. Никаких абстракций, все на самом деле так как я и описывал. пара тектбокс+лейбл. текстбокс подписывается на одно из событий.. введенное число в текстбокс преобразуется в зависимость от выбранной логики (события) и записывается в лейбл. но тут уже не ето важно, а как KeyEventHandler (имя события) привести в string и обратно. в любом случаи спасибо за помощь!!!

Никак. Вы не должны оперировать подписками событий. Еще раз повторю - у вас должно быть одно событие, внутри которого выбирается нужная логика. Как такое сделать - я сказал выше. Не хотите как надо, чтож, изобретайте свои костыли.

Извините. Уверен, в нашем недопонимании, из за отсутствия опыта и недостаточного количества знаний, виноват я. Не пытаюсь изобрести велосипед. Думал что управление выбора события через сравнение string' является костылем, Почему то казалось( и сейчас кажется=) ) что существует метод конвертации имени события в string и обратно textBox1.KeyDown += **имя**, но начинаю понимать что снова ошибаюсь.
